# How to continually iterate through divs with a delay using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have different div columns and would like to perform these steps:

1. iterate through each element every 5 seconds in the first column. A class is added to the element when it is selected and removed when the next element is selected.
2. when it's finished going through the first column, then move to the second column and iterate through each element in that column just like in step 1.
3. When the second column is done, continue iteration in the first column and so on....

HTML markup:

```
<div class="first-column">
  <div class="selected">...</div>
  <div>...</div>
  <div>...</div>
</div>
<div class="second-column">
  <div>...</div>
  <div>...</div>
  <div>...</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you forget to post your code?

Answer (score 1):

You can get all the inner divs with a statement like this:

```
var divs = $('div > div');
```

Call your function repeatedly with *setInterval()*

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/DFqBZ/